# Missing term_id value

Tags: terms

For some reason the `get_term_by` function does not return a value for `term_id`.  It will return the name of the term but not a value for `term_id`.  I'm trying to get the `term_id` of a category basically.

Code being used:

```
get_term_by('name', 'Test', 'category');
```

[image]

[image][image]

Answer (score 2):

Actually it does.

```
["term_id"]=>
int(8)
```

So the value is an integer `8`.

Comment: Hah. Gave it a look myself earlier and totally missed it. Glad he didn't draw the box over it so it would be hidden. Elegant solution mate. Love it.

Comment: Good grief... I thought that was the length and for some reason I thought it was suppose to be returned as string.  Must have read that for some other function.  Thanks for the second set of eyes!